# What is the best way to read nested object from a join query

Tags: java, jooq

Assume I have a model like following

```
class Chest {
  public Id id;
  public List<Drawer> drawers;
  public Price price;
}

class Drawer {
  public Id id;
  public Price price;
}
```

And a JOOQ query to fetch a Chest object with its Drawers:

```
dsl.selectFrom(CHEST.join(DRAWERS).onKey()).where(CHEST.ID.eq(1)).fetch()
```

What is the best way to construct the Chest object from the result of the query above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using `JOIN` to materialise object graphs won't really work well, as you're denormalising your database entities into a table (with duplicates) before you try to normalise the data again in a mapping algorithm. JPA hides these things from you by offering an alternative query language that doesn't expose so many SQL features.

In your particular case, however, you can get this to run via the jOOQ API by using the [`Result.intoGroups()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#intoGroups-org.jooq.Field:A-) methods. Thus:

```
Map<Record, Result<Record>> result = 
    dsl.selectFrom(...).fetch().intoGroups(CHEST.fields());

List<Chest> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Entry<Record, Result<Record>> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    Record chest = entry.getKey();
    Result<Record> drawers = entry.getValue();

    list.add(new Chest(
        chest.into(Id.class),      // These into(Class<?>) methods assume that you
        drawers.into(Drawer.class) // want to use jOOQ's DefaultRecordMapper
    ));
}
```

The above algorithm is probably incomplete, or not exactly what you need. But it'll give you a general idea of what's possible out-of-the-box via jOOQ API.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! `intoGroups` seems what I needed - I'll give it a go. I've already implemented it using java's stream grouping: `stream().collect(Collectors.grouping(...))` but JOOQ's way seems to be definitely better, less boilerplate.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, `Stream` has similar capabilities. You can combine Java 8 APIs with jOOQ APIs, of course. By the way, we've found Java 8 quite limiting ourselves when using it in the jOOQ integration tests, which is why we've created and open-sourced [jOOλ](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/09/10/when-the-java-8-streams-api-is-not-enough/). Perhaps we'll also add some useful shortcuts for grouping in there...

Comment: Haha, jOOλ - cool name, looks like a port of scala's Seq :) Sorry for off topic.